# configure pyinstaller 2.0 on Win 7 cannot import name HOMEPATH

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Maybe this is easy to solve but after hours of googling I am just frustrated and hope someone can help me.

Problem is:

running `configure.py` leads to this

```
from PyInstaller import HOMEPATH, PLATFORM
ImportError: cannot import name HOMEPATH
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should run `configure.py`, if you are installing pyinstaller, please read the free manual (RTFM) [here](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#installing-pyinstaller).

But, if that's not what you are trying to achieve, please then clarify your question!